# Cancelling Simple Tensors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $M,N$ be R-Modules with tensor product $M\otimes N$. Let $\{m_1,\dots,m_n\}$ be a collection of non zero elements of $M$ and $\{p_1, \dots,p_n\} , \{q_1,\dots ,q_n\}$ be collections of elements of $N$. If

$$m_1\otimes p_1+\dots +m_n\otimes p_n = m_1\otimes q_1+\dots +m_n\otimes q_n$$

can we conclude that $p_i=q_i$ for $1\leq i \leq n$?

Comment: Presumably you want some conditions on the $m_i$ (as it stands, they could all be zero).

Comment: Note that this is the same as saying that $m_1 \otimes p_1 + \cdots + m_n \otimes p_n= 0 \implies p_i=0$ for all $i$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Yes, thank you. Edited the Post.

Comment: @trek26: I advise you to consider azif00's equivalent formulation for $n = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and this does not even hold in the case $n=1$. For instance, let $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $M=\mathbb{Z}\big/2\mathbb{Z}$, $N=\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\overline{1}\in M$ is non-zero, but $\overline{1}\otimes 2k=\overline{1}\otimes 0$ for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.